# Resources for grad level math courses

Tags: mathematical-economics, academic-graduate

I am currently waiting on Econ PhD decisions. I thought I could use this time to start brushing up on some coursework. I wished to know if there are any resources for graduate level mathematical methods for economics courses. I browsed some university websites, but could not find reading lists or lecure notes. I have some introduction to real analysis and bit of topology as well. But it has been 2 yrs since I passed out of college. So wanted to get a hold of things. And if you think I can learn something else in this time please drop in your suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: A syllabus with reading recommendations and old exams for UPenn's math camp are here: https://economics.sas.upenn.edu/graduate/course-information/summer-math-camp

Comment: Thank you! This looks very useful.